# How can I make use of the Lambda expression returned by spinServerUp() method in following code

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface, functional-java

I'm learning Java at the moment and I see some code that looks like this:

```
public interface Await {
    boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

```
public Await spinServerUp() {
    this.startServers()
    return (timeout, timeUnit) -> countDownLatch.await(timeout, timeUnit);
}
```

Now, I understand that `countDownLatch` waits for the threads to complete before continuing on.

My question is - how do parameters `timeout` and `timeunit` get passed to the Lambda expression? I can't find any usage examples on my end for this block of code that I'm reading, so I'm a bit confused.

I'm also not sure if I follow the `spinServerUp()` method that well, I understand that it calls `this.startServers()` then returns the Lambda expression - thus giving control to the Lambda expression. Why return the Lambda expression, though?

I've tried to do some research and reading, but I got more confused. Any clarifications would be appreciated

Comment: maybe you can find [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do parameters timeout and timeunit get passed to the Lambda expression?

Just treat the returnValue as a function. Basically same as function you declared in class:

```
Await await = spinServerUp();
await.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

> Why return the Lambda expression though?

Lambda function declaration does nothing util you call it like code snippet above.

The typical usage of lambda is callback. It is something that **will** happen **if** certain event is triggered (e.g. mouse clicked on a button). So it will not do anything if `certain event` is not triggered.

Or for a real world example. Jack told Nick to [call him] if Bob arrived. `Call Jack` is the lambda in this case and it will only be triggered if Bob arrived.

```java
public ThingsToDo planForBobArriving() {
  String personToCall = "Jack";
  return () -> call(personToCall); 
}

public void mainLogic() {
  ThingsToDo thingsToDoWhenBobArrived = planForBobArriving();
  while(keepWaiting) {
    if (bobArrived()) {
       thingsToDoWhenBobArrived.execute(); // call Jack
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, and to test my knowledge to make sure I'm understanding it, by calling `await.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, it still invokes `this.startServers()` correct?

Comment: @GRVY, no, that's done outside of the lambda, when `spinServerUp()` is called. Calling `await.await(...)` only calls `countDownLatch.await`.

Comment: @RobSpoor is right, only  `countDownLatch.await` (whatever is inside the lambda declaration) is executed.

Answer (score 2):

`Await` is a *Functional interface* (i.e. an interface defining only a single abstract method).

And method `spinServerUp()` produces an implementation of this Functional interface (which is expressed in the form of Lambda expression).

Hence, in what ever place that requires an instance of `Await` you can use a *Method reference* `intanceName::spinServerUp()`, where `intanceName` is a reference to the instance of a class that own method `spinServerUp()`, also within the owning class you can use `this` keyword `this::spinServerUp()`.

> how do parameters timeout and timeunit get passed to the Lambda expression?

Suppose you have the following method:

```
public void foo(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit, Await a) {
    a.await(timeout, timeout);
}
```

You can call it like that:

```
foo(5, TimeUnit.MILLI_SCALE, intanceName::spinServerUp()
```

The parameters require by the `Await` contract should be provided by the code that uses it directly by invoking `Await.await()`.

> I understand that it calls the this.startServers() then returns the Lambda expression - thus giving control to the Lambda expression.

If you mean that you think that while `spinServerUp()` gets executed it also fairs the logic of the lambda expression, then it's not correct. A Lambda expression (as well a method references) is just a way to obtain an instance of a Function interface. Lambda basically is an object representing a certain behavior, when you're defining a lambda this behavior **doesn't** get executed.

In order to actually execute the behavior of a lambda expression, you need to plug the reference to it into a code which would invoke the abstract method of the Function interface it's represents (`Await.await()`, `Function.apply()`, `Predicate.test()`, etc.).

*I recommend you to get familiar with these tutorials on [Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [Method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) provided by Oracle*

Comment: Ah thank you! Your example helps, I'll look more into Functional interfaces :)

Comment: @GRVY You'll find more examples and information in the official tutorial provided by Oracle (see the links in the answer) and thing would become more clear.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the lamda to invoke the await function:

```
try {
 if (spinServerUp().await(1, MINUTES)) {
   // do stuff
 }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
// just exit on interruption?
}
```